# Angular: How to keep final animation state when using query() + animate()

Tags: angular, animation

See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mqwJP75zjTUmsqsqRxfH?p=preview

This is with Angular v5.1.3.

There are buttons to toggle between the up+fade-in (opacity 1) and down+fade-out (opacity 0) states. I'm confused why the down state reverts back to the original values after the animation ends, and what I should be doing to cause the animation to hold its final values.

Note that I'm explicitly not using `state()` because of https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18775 (it's not allowed in combination with `query()`). Also, I recognize that I might be able to accomplish this specific example without using `query()`, but I'm more interested in solving this in the general case than I am in making the specific plunker example work.